# Reaction analogous to burning that causes cooling rather than releasing heat

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, nanotechnology

Is it physically and chemically possible to design both a gas and a solid substance, such that there would be a technologically feasible initiation of a chain reaction analogous to the spark that starts a fire, with the unusual feature that the reaction cools the region?

We are familiar with a spark being applied to the surface of a solid surrounded by gas, so that the spark is applied where there are both solid and gas.  Would it be possible to instead start a chain reaction in the gas, with the gas then changing form and affecting the solid?

I acknowledge that I haven't provided any information about the process that initiates the chain reaction, except via the vague analogy with a spark.  For example, perhaps  spraying a liquid catalyst into the gas is what initiates the chain reaction.

Comment: Endothermic reactions are a real things. Look at Wikipedia for them. This is because is quite difficult to get what you mean by analogous here. Opposite, if the reaction must be a chain reaction, I am not aware of such processes. The point is that every step would require activation from a cooled down microscopical surrounding.

Comment: In order for a reaction to be spontaneous and endothermic, it must produce a great increase in entropy. A simple way to increase the entropy is to produce a gas. For example, the reaction $\ce{NaHCO3 + HCl -> NaCl + H2O + CO2}$ is strongly endothermic, but produces a large increase of entropy due to the production of a gas, $\ce{CO2}$. Now it seems dubious that a reaction consuming a gas could be endothermic. It should produce more gas than it consumes. The only case I know is the reaction $\ce{C + CO2 -> 2 CO}$ which happens at around $1000$°C. But it is not a chain reaction.

Comment: I think one would be hard pressed to find an example. The whole point of the "burning" is that the exothermicity of the reaction helps sustain the reaction. A "reverse" process would inhibit the process and thus, be unlikely to be self-sustaining.

Comment: By burning do you mean combustion in an oxygen atmosphere?